# Javascript .sort() returns true/false different than expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

In this code example below, i'm passing in "item" as being either stone or copper. This is meant to get all inventory items, sort alphabetically, and append again overriding the old. My issue is the first time around, the sort function evaluates 'a' as copper, 'b' as stone, and returns -1 (false, correct?). Then, I have it if a value if 0 it removes the element. When adding that element back, it has 'a' as stone and 'b' as copper, again returning -1, and then sorting it with stone first. I'm beyond confused of how/why, and think I've been staring at this too long that I can't see whats wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Minimal reproducable example:

```
var ConsoleButtons = {
    initialize: function() {
    cbOne.addEventListener("click", function() { ConsoleButtons.cbOneClick(); });
    cbOneClick: function() {
        PlayerInventory.addToBag(stone, 1);
        PlayerInventory.addToBag(copper, 1);
    }  
    }
}
var PlayerInventory = {
    initialize: function() {
    plyrInv = document.createElement('div');
    plyrInv.setAttribute('id', "playerInv");
    wrapper.append(plyrInv);
    },
    addToBag: function(item, qty) {
        item.quantity += qty;
        console.log(item.name + item.quantity);
        PlayerInventory.checkInv(item);
    },
    removeFromBag: function(item, qty) {
        item.quantity -= qty;
        if (item.quantity < 0) {
            item.quantity = 0;
        }
        console.log(item.name + item.quantity);
        PlayerInventory.checkInv(item);
    },
    createRescDisp: function(item) {
        if (item.para === undefined || item.para === null) {
            item.para = document.createElement('p');
            item.para.setAttribute('class', 'inventoryItem');
            item.para.setAttribute('id', item);
            item.para.innerHTML = item.name + ": " + item.quantity;
            invParent = document.getElementById('playerInv');
            invParent.appendChild(item.para);
            //Sort: compare a to b.
            //If a is larger than b, return true. else, false.
            invParArr = Array.from(invParent.children);
            //invParArr.sort((a,b) => a.getAttribute('id') > b.getAttribute('id') ? 1 : -1);
            for (i = 0; i < invParArr.length; i++) {
                invParent.append(invParArr[i]);
            }
}
PlayerInventory.initialize();
ConsoleButtons.initialize();
```

Comment: "*and returns -1 (false, correct?)*" no, it means "sort `b` after `a`".

Comment: @VLAZ alternatively, it [`-1`] means that `a` "sinks" underneath of `b`, whereas returning `+1` makes it "float" above `b`.

Comment: What actually *is* the problem here? What is the input, what is the result you get, what is the result you expect?

Comment: On a somewhat related note, do note that your sorting comparator needs to return *three* values: less than zero, more than zero, *and zero*. You're missing the last one, so you're not handling equality between elements. See [Sorting in JavaScript: Shouldn't returning a boolean be enough for a comparison function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24080785) for more information on how `.sort()` uses the result of the comparator.

Comment: The problem is that it compares 'a' as copper to 'b' as stone, returns -1. So, thank you for the clarification on what that actually does, in that case it sorts alphabetically as expected. But then, when stone is removed from the array, then later added back, it compares 'a' as stone, and 'b' as copper, and returns -1, thus sorting b after a and thats copper after stone, which is not alphabetically correct

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Comment: I've editted the original post to reflect what I believe to be the minimal reproducable example, theres a lot there but I don't think I could leave any out to show whats happening

Comment: Almost none of it is needed. All you need is a list of items that you sort. Then you remove an item, add it back, then sort again. No need for anything else like the code which is creating HTML, managing inventory, etc...

Comment: Thank you, but I just can't get anything written out thats simple. I've tried following the guide linked, but it all seems extremely relevant, I simply don't know how to make it how would be helpful. I’ve spent that past 2 days on this issue and it’s melted my brain, I'm sorry, thank you for your help anyways.

Comment: Just a simple list with sorting, removing, then sorting again.  Roughly `var data = ["C","B","A"]; data.sort(); data.shift(); data.push("A"); data.sort();` The issue seems to be with sorting so that is all you should be looking at.